# How to do unstratified (shuffled) k-fold cross validation using R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation

I would like to split my data into k training folds without using stratification (but optionally with shuffling). How would one achieve this in R? All threads that I found so far relate to stratified k-fold which is not what I want. Possibly related to this [CrossValidated thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92904/rs-equivalente-of-scikits-kfold). The equivalent to this in Python would be to use [`sklearn.model_selection.KFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try my lightweight package [splitTools](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=splitTools).

Depending on your use case, you would do something like

```
library(splitTools)

# invert = TRUE to get out-of-sample folds
insample_folds <- create_folds(
  1:nrow(iris), k = 10, type = "basic", seed = 1, shuffle = TRUE
)

# Loop over insample folds to get RMSE per fold
rmses <- numeric(0)
for (fold in insample_folds) {
  fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris[fold, ])
  valid_errors <- iris$Sepal.Length[-fold] - predict(fit, iris[-fold, ])
  rmses <- c(rmses, sqrt(mean(valid_errors^2)))
}

mean(rmses) # 0.312
```